# How can I add a "rate and review" button to my app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm planning on releasing my app soon, I want to have a rate button that sends them to the rating page for my app. Since it isn't released yet how may I do so? Also I created a share button and email sender. I just need to add a link from the email to the page of the app.

Answer (score 3):

On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394030%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

```
MarketplaceReviewTask review = new MarketplaceReviewTask();
review.Show();
```

If you want to build a link you can publish the app without this feature, as soon is approved and active, post an update and in a couple of day the app is published again.

Another possible solution is to send an email with a fixed link to a page that redirects to the rate page, but initially pointing an empty one, as soon the app is published you can update the destination of the redirect to the right address.

Comment: You can also start the submission process, and the product ID is presented *somewhere* while you're submitting it. so you could technically begin a submission, note the ID, and then upload the build again, only submitting once. But in general, the blank MarketplaceReviewTask is probably what is desired.

Comment: Playing around I tried to find the id of the app from the submission, but my impression was that the submission is a different entity and has a different id from the final app. Maybe looking a little more is possible to find also the app id